# How to generate tiff/box in jTessBoxEditor (tesseract) in new app interface?

Tags: tesseract

I learn how to add your font to tesseract. In tutorial about jTessBoxEditor people specify image file in tab "TIFF/BOX generator" and click on "Generate" button.
But in actual version jTessBoxEditor I don't see similiar tab and button.

Screen app UI:
[image]

How to generate? Where "TIFF/BOX generator", "Box Editor" tabs?

Answer (score 0):

I confuse downloading files in sourceforge and download VietOCR3, not jTessBoxEditor. Different programs.